# MYSQL select matching values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables

both have userids on them

i need to select and display data's which are matching from both tables.

Example

Table one have userid 101,120.... and

Table two has userid 101,120,140,155....

i just need to display 101,120 only data s which are matching from both table.

My table structure is simple and have one column `userid` only thanks

Comment: Please read: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mre]

Comment: It's not clear if userid is a comma separated string containing multiple userids or the userid contains 1 userid with many rows.

Comment: @Luuk thanks i hope you need profile view if your'e kind you can fix it what did you get by underrating thanks someone kind answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T.*,T2.*
FROM TABLE1 AS T
  JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T.USERID=T2.USERID
```